# Como se hace para declarar una propiedad de tipo de un tipo de una clase en otra clase en Python?

Tags: python, poo

Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
class Encabezado():
    def __init__(self,pid,pcustomer,pcustnumber,pcity,pstate,puser):
        self.__id=pid
        self.__customerName=pcustomer
        self.__customerNumber=pcustnumber
        self.__city=pcity
        self.__state=pstate
        self.__userName=puser

    def get_Id(self):
        return  self.__id
    def get_CustomerName(self):
        return  self.__customerName
    def get_CustomerNumber(self):
        return  self.__customerNumber
    def get_CustomerCity(self):
        return  self.__city
    def get_CustomerState(self):
        return  self.__state
    def get_UserName(self):
        return  self.__userName

    def set_Id(self, id):
        self.__id = id
    def set_CustomerName(self,name):
          self.__customerName=name
    def set_CustomerNumber(self,number):
          self.__customerNumber=number
    def set_City(self,city):
         self.__city=city
    def set_State(self,state):
         self.__state=state
    def set_UserName(self,user):
         self.__userName=user






class Linea():
    def __init__(self,pid,pinvoiceNumber,ptype,pdueDate,pcurrentDue,
                 pdue1ti5,pdue6ti15,pdue16ti30,pdue31ti60,pdue61ti90,pdue90plus,poutstandingAmount):
        self.__id=pid
        self.__invoiceNumber=pinvoiceNumber
        self.__type=ptype
        self.__dueDate=pdueDate
        self.__currentDue=pcurrentDue
        self.__due1ti5=pdue1ti5
        self.__due6ti15 = pdue6ti15
        self.__due16ti30 = pdue16ti30
        self.__due31ti60 = pdue31ti60
        self.__due61ti90 = pdue61ti90
        self.__due90plus = pdue90plus
        self.__outstandingAmount = poutstandingAmount

    def get_Id(self):
        return  self.__id
    def get_InvoiceNumber(self):
        return  self.__invoiceNumber
    def get_Type(self):
        return  self.__type
    def get_DueDate(self):
        return  self.__dueDate
    def get_CurrentDue(self):
        return  self.__currentDue
    def get_Due1ti5(self):
        return  self.__due1ti5
    def get_Due6ti15(self):
        return  self.__due6ti15
    def get_Due16ti30(self):
        return  self.__due16ti30
    def get_Due31ti60(self):
        return  self.__due31ti60
    def get_Due61ti90(self):
        return  self.__due61ti90
    def get_Due90plus(self):
        return  self.__due90plus
    def get_OutstandingAmount(self):
        return  self.__outstandingAmount




    def set_Id(self,id):
        self.__id=id
    def set_InvoiceNumber(self,inumber):
        self.__invoiceNumber=inumber
    def set_Type(self,type):
        self.__type=type
    def set_DueDate(self,due):
        self.__dueDate=due
    def set_CurrentDue(self,current):
        self.__currentDue=current
    def set_Due1ti5(self,due115):
        self.__due1ti5=due115
    def set_Due6ti15(self,due615):
        self.__due6ti15=due615
    def set_Due16ti30(self,due630):
        self.__due16ti30=due630
    def set_Due31ti60(self,due3160):
        self.__due31ti60=due3160
    def set_Due61ti90(self,due6190):
        self.__due61ti90=due6190
    def set_Due90plus(self,due90):
        self.__due90plus=due90
    def set_OutstandingAmount(self,outstand):
        self.__outstandingAmount=outstand





class Factura():
    def __init__(self,pid,penc=[],plines=[]):
        self.__id=pid
        self.__encabezado=penc
        self.__lineas=plines

    def get_Id(self):
        return  self.__id

    def set_Id(self,id):
        self.__id=id

    def get_Encabezado(self):
        return self.__encabezado

    def set_Encabezado(self, enc):
        self.__encabezado.append(enc)

    def get_Lineas(self):
        return self.__lineas

    def set_Lineas(self, plineas):
        self.__lineas.append(plineas)
```

Como hago para especificarle a la clase Factura que encabezado es de tipo Encabezado y lineas es de tipo Linea ???

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras, si solo quieres una guía en tu editor puedes usar la sugerencia de tipo de python, donde se hace `variable:tipo` por ejemplo en una función `def set_Encabezado(self, enc:Encabezado):` pero si quieres validar que solo sea de tipo `Encabezado` entonces deberás hacer `if type(enc)!=Encabezado: raise ValueError()` o puedes usar `isinstance`.

Comment: Algo similar a eso set_Encabezado(self, enc:Encabezado): que valide que es tipo Encabezado y en el get devuelva un Tipo Encabezado pero en este caso sería un arreglo entonces no tengo idea, digamos en el set lo que quiero pasar es un arreglo de Encabezados y un arreglo de lineas y en el get quiero obtener un arreglo de encabezados y líneas tambien

Comment: Dos opciones, puedes hacer una combinación de lo que te dije, es decir, usar la sugerencia de tipo y la validación, con lo que función quedaría `def set_Encabezado(self, enc:Encabezado): if type(enc)!=Encabezado: raise ValueError(); #resto de tu código`. O si quieres algo más profesional usar el módulo `typing`

Comment: Investigando un poco más me he dado cuenta que existe un intérprete de python capaz de hacer esa validación con tan solo la sugerencia de tipo, el intérprete se llama [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). Es algo interesante si tu idea es definir variables de tipo estático y no dinámico.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que Python es un lenguaje de [tipado dinámico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) y por ende las variables pueden ser de diferentes tipos.

Si estas usando [Python 3.5+](https://realpython.com/lessons/type-hinting/) puedes hacer uso de "type hints" o "anotaciones de tipos" que se incluyen de la manera que Christian menciona en su comentario:

```
variable: tipo
```

o en funciones:

```
def nombre_funcion() -> tipo_retorno:
```

Esto permite hacer ciertos chequeos y validaciones de tipo como las que encontrarias en lenguajes de [tipado estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos#Tipado_est%C3%A1tico).

Espero sea de ayuda!